# How to automatically delete old photos

Tags: ios, photos, storage

My daughter's phone is always full.
Deleting photos is 'hard because I want them all'

How can I set up the phone (or can I buy an app) that deletes the oldest photo on the phone when one is taken?

Equally I would like to do this for videos.

I DO NOT want any of them backed up or a backup service, unless it's also free and that doesn't stop working when 'full'

Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

Apple has 5GB associated with the Apple ID.

It is free so backup to that.

The idea of deleting the oldest photos to make space is fraught with danger - the oldest one may the the most treasured... And good luck dealing with the fallout if it was her only pic of her best friend etc.

Get your daughter to start sorting her photos and having a folder / album of important aka "must never delete" photos so weekly or monthly housekeeping can be easier.

Comment: Tough love moment. Back up phone and then erase it.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Solar Mike that auto-delete, even if doable, is to be avoided. Here are a few things your daughter can do:

1. As suggested, encourage her to periodically cull the "not so good" or "very similar to the other" photos. Videos take up a lot more space than photos, so just deleting a few videos will help (in iPhone Photos, select the Albums tab > Media Types > Videos)
2. If she has her own Apple ID (and therefore her own 5GB free quota of iCloud), go to iPhone Settings > Profile > iCloud > turn iCloud Photos ON and check mark 'Optimize iPhone storage'.
3. Go to iPhone Settings > Camera > Formats, and ensure that 'High Efficiency' is check marked. HEIC (photo) and HEVC (video) formats take up only half as much space as JPG / MOV files.